# ProcessContainerFork.js pm2 'Unexpected token import' node 14

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm aware a few similar questions have been asked before - mainly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834021/pm2-unexpected-token-import). However, whatever I try to do I cannot get this to work. Screenshot of the issue below. This happens when I attempt to run `pm2 start api`.

[image]

My `ecosystem.config.js` is:

```js
const nodeServer = (role, debugPort) => ({
    name: role,
    script: 'server/server.js',
    watch: role == 'api' ? ['client', 'server'] : ['server'],
    ignore_watch: ['node_modules'],
    max_memory_restart: '4G',
    node_args: `--inspect=${debugPort}`,
    env: {
      NODE_OPTIONS: '--max-old-space-size=4096',
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
      SERVER_ROLE: role,
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
})

module.exports = {
    apps: [
      nodeServer('api', 9229),
      nodeServer('task', 9228),
      nodeServer('scheduler', 9227),
    ]
}
```

PM2 is installed globally on my system running **5.1.0** *(which I believe is the current latest)*. Node version is **14.13.0**. I get the same error if I try on node versions 10 & 12. I'm really struggling to figure this one out.

Comment: You should execute the command: `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` instead of `pm2 start api`. Once the pm2 apps are up and running, then the command `pm2 (start  | stop | restart) api ` would be applicable.

Comment: I am using `pm2` version `3.5.0` and `node` version `v14.16.0` and your `ecosystem.config.js` file works correctly for me when I execute the command `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`

Comment: @DhruvShah that is working, thank you!! Clearly it is something to do with later versions of PM2