# Node.js app on Kubenetes crashing with error SyntaxError: Unexpected token import for PM2

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I have a Node.js application deployed in Kubernetes and my docker file looks like the following:

```
FROM node:8.9.4
RUN mkdir -p /opt/amy-app-folder
RUN chown -R node:node /opt
WORKDIR /opt/my-app-folder
COPY dist /opt/my-app-folder
RUN npm install pm2 -g
EXPOSE 8000
USER node
CMD ["pm2-docker", "bin/www.js"]
```

This was working fine until I recently did a deployment for the application. I have configured the CI/CD job in such a way that it will build and deploy the application once I merge the PR to the `development` branch. When I checked the pods, it is showing `CrashLoopBackOff` as the status of the pod in which my app is running.

I checked the logs using the command

```
$kubectl logs -f my-app-name-qa-d8744bf4f-sh6ks -n wea-qa --tail 1000
```

It is showing the `pm2` has been crashed with the following error message

```
2022-03-21T11:50:46: PM2 log: App [www:0] starting in -fork mode-
2022-03-21T11:50:46: PM2 log: App [www:0] online
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:30
    import(url.pathToFileURL(process.env.pm_exec_path));
    ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
2022-03-21T11:50:46: PM2 log: App [www:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2022-03-21T11:50:46: PM2 log: Script /opt/my-appl/bin/www.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
2022-03-21T11:50:50: PM2 log: 0 application online, retry = 3
2022-03-21T11:50:52: PM2 log: 0 application online, retry = 2
2022-03-21T11:50:54: PM2 log: 0 application online, retry = 1
2022-03-21T11:50:56: PM2 log: 0 application online, retry = 0
2022-03-21T11:50:56: PM2 log: Stopping app:www id:0
2022-03-21T11:50:56: PM2 error: app=www id=0 does not have a pid
2022-03-21T11:50:57: PM2 log: PM2 successfully stopped
```

The only change I have made in the code is to add a `console.log` and it is removed later. Now, this is the `staging` version of my application and I checked the code with the `master` branch, which is running fine in production. There is no change in the code and so I am stuck here and don't know what to do next. As the pod is stopped, I can't go inside the pod and run commands. I redeployed the code again, but still, the pod is starting, and then it is crashed.

I am able to run the code in my local machine and there I am not using Kubernetes or Docker. My node version in local is `12.0.0`

Can someone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps `import` is not working with that nodejs version. I would suggest upgrading your pod's version to v12.x or trying to reproduce the issue locally by downgrading your nodejs version to v8.x

Comment: actually, from this other answer, I would upgrade nodejs to +13: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436580/1971120

Comment: okay. But until 2-3 weeks back I have triggered a deployment and at that time there was no issue. Actually this ap has been running for almost 2 years without any issues. Not sure what happened now.

Comment: hmm... from the stacktrace, it seems it's actually pm2 failing, and if you see this line: `RUN npm install pm2 -g` it is installing the latest version of pm2 when the image is built. Perhaps when you triggered a new image, node just tried to use a new pm2 version. A version not compatible with node v8.x

Comment: how about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840576/1971120 (it's from 2 years ago thou)

Comment: hmm I think this deserves to publish an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think it's happening with your app:

### The problem is not with your app's code

...but with Nodejs not recognizing `import` when trying to run `pm2`.
The nodejs version v8.x probably does not support importing modules this way.

### Now, why this is failing *now*?

Well, Docker is installing the latest version of `pm2` to run your app here:

```sh
RUN npm install pm2 -g
```

Therefore, when you added something to your code, the new build must have downloaded a new version of `pm2`, one not compatible with that nodejs version. This seems to be similar to this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840576/1971120

### What can you do with this?

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436580/1971120) (another question), I would suggest you to upgrade nodejs to +v13 (using a LTS version would be ideal), but in case you can not do that, stick with a compatible pm2 version in the docker descriptor like this:

```sh
RUN npm install pm2@x.y.z -g
```

Where `x.y.z` is a compatible version.

Comment: Done that. The app is up and running. Now need to update the production too. Fingers crossed. Thanks a lot for your sincere help. People like you make the world a better place to live :)

Comment: your answer made my day 200% better, thanks!